# Make spaces unbreakable when it's obvious that a line-break should not occur (French specificity)

Tags: feature-request, formatting, input-methods

Keyboards, most software and basic input forms found on the web are usually too simple to cope with standard French typography conventions.
However, I'd like to suggest a simple improvement that (I think) cannot do any harm, and would help post formatting a bit, by avoiding hanging punctuation.

Spaces appear before and after several punctuation signs in French. Conventions may vary with countries, but very often *when there is such a space* it should not be just a simple space but an unbreakable space¹.

Compare what your mobile phone may display:

> La mise en forme de ce texte n'est pas «
>   convenable », il devient difficile de le lire
>   ! ne pensez-vous pas ?

with what you would obtain using no-break spaces appropriately:

> La mise en forme de ce texte est plus
>   « habituelle », et il est plus facile de le
>   lire ! N'est-ce pas ?

I usually don't like automatic rewriting, but I think we could safely enforce a few very simple characters rewriting patterns on this site, turning normal spaces into unbreakable spaces where needed. At least in the following cases:

(I use `.` to denote any non-space character, and `_` is a placeholder for the no-break space.)

- `. :` → `._:`
- `. ;` → `._;`
- `. !` → `._!`
- `. ?` → `._?`
- `« .` → `«_.`
- `. »` → `._»`

It may work just like the quote rewriting `".` → `“.` and `."` → `.”` that is performed on titles.
And code blocks should better be excluded from such a rewrite (hardly any code block can be found on the site currently, but anyway…).

Like others, I'm pretty tired of fixing the dangling symbols in titles, especially because I know that it would take roughly 15 minutes of work to deal with this once and for all, for everyone. When I fix titles with my phone, I don't even bother, and quite often someone has to come after me.

So I kindly ask the SE team to implement such a change, or to let us implement it.

—
<sub>1. Some should in fact be turned into *narrow no-break spaces* (U+202F), but I'm giving up with these since some broken browsers still fail to render them properly.</sub>

Comment: This is a follow-up for http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/39/non-breaking-spaces-and-punctuation-on-stack-exchange

Comment: You shouldn't give up on narrow-no breaks. Most of the recent browsers have no problems with them, and slipping the problem under the rug is not very serviceable, neither for the users nor for the developers.

Comment: I agree with @Evpok, and I'm one whose browser is misbehaving (big space).

Comment: I can't upvote again :-(

Comment: I've added a client-side implementation of these rewrite rules, as suggested above, into version 1.16 of the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script. It uses narrow no-break spaces, although, honestly, I can't really see much visual difference between them and normal no-break spaces. Let me know if you find any problems with it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Fantastic! I just tried and it works for me™. I will report any problem if I find one. Thanks!

Comment: Est-ce que la question est résolue?